# Nodejs - Merge objects with minimal memory footprint

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization

I would like to merge 2 objects with no colliding fields. I don't care about losing the original objects. I am aware that spread syntax can be used to achieve this task as following:

```
const x = { a: 1 }
const y = { b: 2 }
const z = { ...x, ...y } // { a:1, b:2 }
```

But this will cause full copy of both x and y into at totally new object. Is there a way to do this in a more memory efficient manner without needing to set keys of object one by one?

Comment: What part of your result `{ a:1, b:2 }` are you trying to avoid copying?  Those are primitive values.  To put them in a new object, there is no way to reference the originals, you have to assign them to new properties in the new object.  Not sure what you're trying to avoid?

Comment: Are you doing this merge millions of times? Do these objects each have thousands and thousands of properties? Is your node.js app serving 100k requests per minute? Is your profiler showing you massive garbage generation with accompanying latency spikes? No? Then it doesn't matter.

Comment: @jfriend00 As you can see in the below answer, you can avoid copying at least one of the object's fields, and achieve merger of two objects. Instead of using numbers, I should have used heap-allocated data type in this example, but it is VERY CLEAR what I am asking. The question is not relevant to data being primitive or not, or data residing in stack or heap. What I am trying to achieve is as simple as: "How do I avoid data copying as much as possible and achieve a merger of two objects?".

Comment: @JaredSmith I haven't asked you whether my app has a bottleneck in memory and gc, and when should I start thinking about optimization. I have asked  "How do I avoid data copying as much as possible and achieve a merger of two objects?". Your answer is COMPLETELY irrelevant. Your contempteous answer is exactly why MANY people find StackOverflow toxic.

Comment: @AhmetYazıcı There is no more efficient way to merge two objects into a new object than what you are currently doing. So if you want to do something different, you will need to tell us more about your requirements and the problems you are facing with your current code.

Comment: "Your answer is COMPLETELY irrelevant." It's not an answer, it's a comment. And it's not irrelevant. It is my reasoned opinion as a Javascript expert that your question is pointless: Javascript does not afford a great deal of control over memory allocations. How those allocations happen is implementation-dependent and further impacted by the fact the many Javascript implementations use a JIT compiler so the memory allocated may change between one execution and the next for any given section of code. In addition, contorting code in an attempt to micro-optimize...

Comment: when it can't possibly make any noticeable difference in the runtime execution makes it harder to read, harder to maintain/extend, more likely to have bugs, and generally cuts against the grain of creating effective software that makes the world a better place as opposed to crappy software that makes it worse. As for toxic, I have been on Stack Overflow for a decade now. You are the 5,938th person I've had to try to explain this to. I'm kinda over it. So I apologize for the tone of the earlier comment (and this one too), but definitely **not** the contents. You are barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Bergi and JaredSmith I do understand both of you. I didn't mention about the use case or the problem I encountered because there is not one. I didn't mean to ask this question to fix or change a production grade code, but to learn. I clarified the question to specify that there is no need to create a new object, and already existing objects can be used. As far as I am concerned, I am satisfied with the below answer from Barmar.

Comment: In the future, I'd recommend not claiming that "it is VERY CLEAR what I'm asking" when multiple people commented that they were not clear about some parts of your question.   It matters not what is clear to you.  It matters what is clear to people reading your question.  If it's not clear to them, you can't tell them it is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign()` to merge one object into the other, so it only has to copy the second object.

The first argument to `Object.assign()` is the object that's updated with the properties of all the other arguments.

```js
const x = { a: 1 }
const y = { b: 2 }
Object.assign(x, y);
console.log(x);
```